# Manipulate Chrome Dev Tools with Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there some way to manipulate the Chrome Dev Tools using a python script?
Specifically, I would like to write a python script that opens the browser, sends Javascript commands, and retrieves the output. Is there an easy way to go about doing this using existing python packages?

Comment: Have you looked into headless browsers like PhantomJS? Darn, beat me to it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) for this. PhantomJS is a headless Webkit, shortly put a scriptable Chrome without a GUI.
PhantomJS can, as the name implies, be scripted via Javascript, just like you'd like.

Sample script from their homepage:

```
console.log('Loading a web page');
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://www.phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function (status) {
  //Page is loaded!
  phantom.exit();
});
```

You can have your Python script invoke the PhantomJS script with the necessary parameters, wait for it to finish and then retrieve the output.